# WebStorm 2020.1.3 Backspace auto delete empty object/string

Tags: ide, webstorm

Whenever I write `""` or `{}` and want to delete it because it's empty I just go inside and hit backspace
but whenever I do that I finish with `"` or `}`.

Is there any solution to enable this back or did JetBrains just removed the functionality?

One solution is to use <kbd>CTRL + Backspace</kbd> but would be nice that have this option without <kbd>CTRL</kbd>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your IDE settings: sounds like some options are disabled. I checked in PhpStorm 2020.1.3 version in plain `.js` file. These options must be enabled:

**Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Smart Keys**

- `Insert paired brackets (), [], {}, <>`
- `Insert pair quote`

[image]

Comment: This is for inserting brackets tho I'm looking for when I want to remove them.
After some testing it depends on the file type I'm editing.

Comment: Deleting works just fine for me in plain `.js` file. In other file types/languages -- it may work differently (as the same feature needs to be implemented separately per language in majority of cases).